# Listbox, mouse wheel scroll issue

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Whenever I try scrolling through list Box created by  Excel Vba , using mouse wheel . Excel sheet tend to freeze up .

have any one experienced the same ?

Excel version that I am using is 2007.

Comment: On what OS? I'd suspect compatibility, it being so old.

Comment: Windows 7 ultimate